# How sum query json array object base on other column on postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I using postgres 14.2 and have 3 column example **name**, **name_adds**, **aditional**

and have rules:

1. **name** and **name_adds** can be fill with same value or not.
   Example -> **name (john)** and **name_adds (doe)** or both value is **(john)**
2. **additional** column can be 2 format value on the below

- first value can be

```
{"default":[{"value_1": 100, "value_2": 0.1},{"value_1": 200, "value_2": 0.2}], 
 "non_default":[{"value_1": 200, "value_2": 0.1}, {"value_1": 400, "value_2": 0.1}]}
```

- second value can be

```
[
{
    "value_1": 10,
    "value_2": 11
},
{
    "value_1": 1,
    "value_2": 19
}
]
```

3. to sum default -> value_1 (**name** == **name_adds**)
4. to sum non_default -> value_1 (**name** != **name_adds**)

How I can sum format 1 or 2 on point 2 base on rule point 3 and 4. For logic like below

```
if (name == name_adds) {
    if (additional contain default) {
       sum (default->value_1)
    } else {
       // format 2.2
       sum (value_1)
    }
} else {
    if (additional contain non_default) {
       sum (default->value_1)
    } else {
       // format 2.2
       sum (value_1)
    }
}
```

Expected result:

example on table, lets say I have table like below

```
name    name_adds   additional
---------------------------------------------------------------
john    john      {"default":[{"value_1": 100, "value_2": 0.1}, 
                  {"value_1": 200, "value_2": 0.2}],"non_default": 
                  [{"value_1": 200, "value_2": 0.1}, {"value_1": 400, 
                   "value_2": 0.1}]}

john     doe     {"default":[{"value_1": 100, "value_2": 0.1}, 
                  {"value_1": 200, "value_2": 0.2}],"non_default": 
                  [{"value_1": 200, "value_2": 0.1}, {"value_1": 400, 
                   "value_2": 0.1}]}

downy    downy    [{"value_1": 10, "value_2": 11},{"value_1": 1,"value_2": 19}]

downy    dan      [{"value_1": 10, "value_2": 11},{"value_1": 1,"value_2": 19}]
```

and expected table as

```
name    name_adds   sum_result
---------------------------------------------------------------
john    john        300

john     doe        600

downy    downy      11

downy    dan        11
```

I have doing like demo link below, but still not as expected
[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ff64419f97cf43cb012c8c5f08ca5c5e)

Comment: In your question, the second value does not contain default and also not contain non-default.

Comment: yes, second value on point two can be like that @Mark

Comment: based on your expectation, I added the new answer, hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as (
        select
            name,
            name_adds,
            (name = name_adds) name_as_adds,
            jsonb_path_query(additional,'$.default[*].value_1') ::numeric with_default
            ,jsonb_path_query(additional,'$.non_default[*].value_1')::numeric with_no_default
            ,jsonb_path_query(additional,'$[*].value_1')::numeric as ignore_defaults
from test_json),
cte2 as (
    select
        name, name_adds,
        case when ignore_defaults is null and name_as_adds then with_default
             when ignore_defaults is null and name_as_adds is false then with_no_default
             when ignore_defaults is not null then ignore_defaults
        end as cases
    from cte)
select name, name_adds, sum(cases) as sum_result from cte2 group by 1, 2 order by 1 desc;
```